# Is the floccinaucinihilipilification question a question that really deserves so many downvotes? Why/Why not?

Tags: discussion

Why ['A single word which can be used in the place of floccinaucinihilipilification whithout losing the nuances of its meaning'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178199/a-single-word-which-can-be-used-in-the-place-of-floccinaucinihilipilification-wh) got a lot of downvotes?
(-5 at the time when I wrote this post)

Comment: Can you give a link please?

Comment: Yes http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/is-the-floccinaucinihilipilification-question-a-question-that-really-deserves-so?noredirect=1#comment17498_4858 @Mitch

Comment: The link leads us to this question, is that a joke?

Comment: Very few of the free online dictionaries actually make the distinction that it is what some people have termed 'a joke word'; one or two say 'used jocularly' or 'a curiosity' but hardly enough to warrant downvotes for asking for a synonym. 'Joke word' or not it has a meaning.

Answer (score 5):

I downvoted the question, and also posted an answer. I downvoted it because *floccinaucinihilipilification* is a joke word that has never been seriously used in any context except as an example of a long word. (Prove me wrong!) For that reason, it was difficult for me to perceive it as a serious question. If I'm wrong about that, I sincerely apologize.

Comment: I don't think the OP isn't using it for it's length or he/she wouldn't be requesting a different word.

Comment: Perhaps asking @ElberichSchneider if he was asking a serious question in comments might have clarified the matter.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the floccinaucinihilipilification question a question that really deserves so many downvotes? Why/Why not?

Sadly, the simple and very boring answer to your the question is yes it does because the community decided to downvote the post. Whether a post truly deserves downvotes is always somewhat subjective but this particular post has a vote count of +3/-9. Having a 1:3 vote ratio is very much telling us that the community agrees with the downvote message:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

The more interesting question, in my opinion, is *why* the post apparently deserves so many downvotes. I think phenry's response is a good place to start.